# change permission folder and underliyng folders chmod 553 to 555

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod

i am helping a friend of mine setting up his nas remotely, unfortunately it seems the ftp program i use for this doesn't have access to some folders as permissions are set to chmod 553.
unfortunately is is like impossible to go and change all folders manually to 555.
how can i change chmod for the main folder and all underlying folders in one command?

Kind greats

Matthieu

Answer (score 1):

Use the -R option:

```
chmod -R 555 main_dir_name
```

From [chmod manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod):

> -R, --recursive
>
> change files and directories recursively

Comment: thank you, 
i will give it a go.. !